# Storing data between requests in Next.js (server side)

Tags: next.js

I am developing a small project in Next.js, which is a game. I want to add a combat system that requires a large number of requests. Normally, I would use WebSockets, but this isn't really feasible due to serverless constraints and I don't want to set up a separate instance. Currently, I store data for the duration of a session - combat in the game - in a database in a special table.

What is the correct and optimal way in Next.js to temporarily store data between HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding storage:

- If you want to clear data on page refresh, use [`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState).
- If you want to clear data when you close the tab or navigate to a new domain, use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).
- If you want the data to persist when you close the window, use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).
- If you want a more rich ways to store data, use [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

If you just mean caching by itself, then if you want to **avoid reloading data** from server-side, then you have a few options:

- If you want to fetch data each time you load the page, use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props). You can cache your server-side function calls, using an LRU cache or similar.
- If you want to fetch data at build time, use [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props).
- If you want to fetch data at different times during the lifetime of actions on a page, use [`swr`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/client-side#client-side-data-fetching-with-swr). You can use `useEffect` to do this, but if your data is going to be cachable, `swr` is better.

---

I think for this situation, you want to go for an `IndexedDB` for storage, and use `swr` to speak to your backend API, especially if you are doing a bunch of different requests. `swr` is super fast and will allow you to easily do caching.